# Appropriate design pattern for developing rules and outcomes

Tags: design-patterns, python

In the exercice i´m developing bellow, i´m applying the **chain of responsibility** pattern. The pattern works correctly but i don´t think it's the best approach. I think the **rule design** pattern should be a better fit but there´s no much good examples about it using python.

My questions for you are:

1. Do you think this could be done with other pattern?
2. Is the **chain of responsibility** pattern acceptable for this?
3. Should i study the Rule design (in other languages if i have to) to apply in python?

The exercice is the following:

Supose you have Patients with health conditions such as:

1. F: Fever
2. H: Healthy
3. D: Diabetes
4. T: Tuberculosis

In this exercice drugs are provided to all patients. It is not possible to target a specific patient. This is the list of available drugs:

1. As: Aspirin
2. An: Antibiotic
3. Insulin
4. Paracetamol

Drugs can change patients’ states. They can cure, cause side effects or even kill a patient if not properly prescribed. Drugs effects are described by the following rules:

1. Aspirin cures Fever;
2. Antibiotic cures Tuberculosis;
3. A sick patient not receiving the right medicines remains sick, if not explicitly mentioned otherwise;
4. Insulin prevents diabetic subject from dying, does not cure Diabetes;
5. If insulin is mixed with antibiotic, healthy people catch Fever;
6. Paracetamol cures Fever;
7. Paracetamol kills subject if mixed with aspirin;

Input

Parameter 1

List of patients' health status codes, separated by a comma. e.g. “D,F,F” means we have 3 patients, one with diabetes and two with fever.

Parameter 2

List of drugs codes, separated by a comma, e.g. “As,I” means patients will be treated with Aspirin and Insulin.

Output

The result should be sent to stdout. It should be a comma separated string with number of patients with a given state, following the format: F:NP,H:NP,D:NP,T:NP,X:NP (NP:number of people)

Comment: ...also, please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898075/appropriate-design-pattern-for-developing-rules-and-outcomes

Answer (score 0):

I think the rule design pattern can work here. What you need is a model of the patiences state that doesn't care about the order in which the rules are applied.

For example, if you process the rule that aspirin cures fever before processing a rule that causes a fever you end up with a fever when you shouldn't.

So instead of fever being a binary state (fever/no fever), model it as caught or not and cured or not.

Then only after all other rules are applied do you evaluate if the patient has a fever.